# XPath query to fetch value of custom attribute

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to extract "yes" from the following HTML using XPath locator.

The problem is that `div` tag has a class, which is fine, but the `span` does not have a class. It only has a bunch of custom attributes.

*HTML Code:*

```
<div class="bcdef"> 
<span lalalala="no" hahahaha="yes"> </span>

-----a lot of other stuff-------------
</div>
```

How can I fetch the attribute value?

Comment: `//div[@class='bcdef']/span/@hahahaha`

Comment: try this xpath `//div/span[@hahahaha='yes']`

Comment: @JRodDynamite your solution is working thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the following XPath to fetch the attribute value of a tag:

```
//div[@class='bcdef']/span/@hahahaha
```

Once you locate the tag, simply use the attribute name to fetch the value.